# Images working in local file, not showing in online site?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code I am using, I'll use, for example, a Jumbotron via Bootstrap.

CSS

```
.divA           {
            margin: 30px 0;
            background-image: url("Images/pup.jpg");
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-position: 30% 30%;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron divA" id="top">
     <div class="container">
      <h1><font color="#0059d4" face="Fresca">Puppys!</font></h1>
      <p><font color="#0059d4" face="Roboto Condensed">I love puppa :D</font></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="the-blog.html" role="button">View pups!</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

It shows on my local computer like this...

[image: local]

But on the site like this...

[image: site]

Any help?

Funny thing is, the same code here...

```
<div class="divI">
            <a target="_blank" href="****">
                <img width="600" src="Images/unnamed.jpg">
            </a>
```

Works totally fine on both, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks :D

Comment: keep in mind this is for all images (exempting the divI above) on the site, not just jumbotrons, but thumbnails too... (carousals work fine as well)

Comment: Have you checke the file "Images/pup.jpg" really being on the server? Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: i wouldn't know how to sorry! how do i do it?

Comment: You'll need to host your images and html pages online in order to show to the public. For temporary solution you can host your image on https://imgbb.com/. For long term you will need to get a web hosting provider like https://my.godaddy.com/

Comment: Your "funny thing, the same code works" example is using a different image file. Does that `<img>` work with the pup.jpg image?